# How to find Seaborn version

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have installed  Seaborn  in my machine.
The Seaborn is working fine. I need to find the version of Seaborn installed.
What command do I use to find the version of the Seaborn?

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58648739/2336654

Answer (score 20):

Use `__version__`

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.__version__

'0.7.1'
```

Comment: `__version__` is just a common convention, it may not work for other packages.  The correct *command* is `pip show seaborn`.

Comment: I'm trying those lines in my jupyter notebook right now and receiving the error message "AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute '__version__'"