# How to check if python package is latest version programmatically?

Tags: python, pip, gekko

How do you check if a package is at its latest version programmatically in a script and return a true or false?

I can check with a script like this:

```py
package='gekko'
import pip
if hasattr(pip, 'main'):
    from pip import main as pipmain
else:
    from pip._internal import main as pipmain
pipmain(['search','gekko'])
```

or with command line:

```
(base) C:\User>pip search gekko
gekko (0.2.3)  - Machine learning and optimization for dynamic systems
  INSTALLED: 0.2.3 (latest)
```

But how do I check programmatically and return true or false?

Comment: not a complete solution but it might give you some ideas.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888027/python-and-pip-list-all-versions-of-a-package-thats-available

Comment: Doesn't pip have an api you can call into?

Comment: If you can make use of it, Python 3.8 has improved support for this kinda stuff, at least on the *what’s installed locally* side of it.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html

Comment: `pip` does not have an API.  You might want to watch [`pip-api`](https://github.com/di/pip-api) project, but there is not much there yet.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## Fast Version (Checking the package only)

The code below calls the package with an unavailable version like `pip install package_name==random`. The call returns all the available versions. The program reads the latest version.

The program then runs `pip show package_name` and gets the current version of the package.

If it finds a match, it returns True, otherwise False.

This is a reliable option given that it stands on `pip`

```
import subprocess
import sys
def check(name):
    latest_version = str(subprocess.run([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '{}==random'.format(name)], capture_output=True, text=True))
    latest_version = latest_version[latest_version.find('(from versions:')+15:]
    latest_version = latest_version[:latest_version.find(')')]
    latest_version = latest_version.replace(' ','').split(',')[-1]

    current_version = str(subprocess.run([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'show', '{}'.format(name)], capture_output=True, text=True))
    current_version = current_version[current_version.find('Version:')+8:]
    current_version = current_version[:current_version.find('\\n')].replace(' ','') 

    if latest_version == current_version:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

#### Edit 2021: The code below no longer works with the new version of pip

The following code calls for `pip list --outdated`:

```py
import subprocess
import sys

def check(name):
    reqs = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'list','--outdated'])
    outdated_packages = [r.decode().split('==')[0] for r in reqs.split()]
    return name in outdated_packages
```

Comment: I have updated it. Now it checks only the package the user is interested in. I have put both alternatives.

Comment: Usually `if (boolean): return True else: return False` is better just to `return boolean`

Comment: It's not good to use "0" as a bogus version number, because sometimes this will just go ahead and install a package! (try `pip install p==0` for example).

Comment: I have used ```random``` I am sure there is no random version

Comment: The latest version trick is no longer working in current versions of pip.

Comment: It should be noted that this will not work in versions of python before 3.7 as subprocess.run has no capture_output option before that version.

Answer (score 18):

To just check the latest version on PyPi (for Python 3.6 and up):

```bash
pip install requests
```

Then:

```
import requests

package = 'django'  # replace with the package you want to check
response = requests.get(f'https://pypi.org/pypi/{package}/json')
latest_version = response.json()['info']['version']
```

Answer (score 17):

My project [`johnnydep`](https://github.com/wimglenn/johnnydep) has this feature.

In shell:

```
pip install --upgrade pip johnnydep
pip install gekko==0.2.0
```

In Python:

```
>>> from johnnydep.lib import JohnnyDist
>>> dist = JohnnyDist("gekko")
>>> dist.version_installed  
'0.2.0'
>>> dist.version_latest 
'0.2.3'
```

Comment: When I run this in the Windows Command Prompt, I get ANSI escape codes that make the result unreadable. I think you might want to fix this?

Comment: I have colorama==0.4.1 and structlog==19.2.0, and yes, I do see escape codes with that command as well. If it helps I'm running this on Windows 10.0.17763.195, 
Python 3.7.4. I don't have a chance right now to post an issue unfortunately.

Comment: @user541686  This was [issue232](https://github.com/hynek/structlog/issues/232), resolved in structlog v20.1.0 released today. Thanks for the report.

Answer (score 10):

### Checking Installed version:

One way to check installed version is just to access the `__version__` attribute of the top-level namespace:

```
>>> import gekko
>>> gekko.__version__
'0.2.0'
```

Unfortunately not all projects set this attribute, it's just a common convention in Python. When they don't have a version attribute, you can use [`importlib.metadata`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html#distribution-versions) to query the package version. This way does not actually require importing the package itself, since it's retrieved from the package metadata which gets written out when the package was installed.

```
>>> import importlib.metadata
>>> importlib.metadata.version("gekko")
'0.2.0'
```

This functionality is available since Python 3.8. In older Python versions, you can use `pkg_resources` similarly, which is a part of `setuptools`:

```
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> pkg_resources.get_distribution("gekko").version
'0.2.0'
```

### Checking Latest version:

There isn't currently a way to do this within stdlib. But my project [`luddite`](https://github.com/jumptrading/luddite) has this feature:

```
>>> import luddite
>>> luddite.get_version_pypi("gekko")
'0.2.3'
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick at least for demo purposes. Simply call `isLatestVersion` with the name of the package you would like to check. If you are using this somewhere important you would want to try/catch the url request as internet access may not be available. Also note that if the package is not installed `isLatestVersion` will return False.

This is tested for Python 3.7.4 and Pip 19.0.3.

```py
import pip
import subprocess
import json
import urllib.request
from pip._internal.operations.freeze import freeze

def isLatestVersion(pkgName):
    # Get the currently installed version
    current_version = ''
    for requirement in freeze(local_only=False):
        pkg = requirement.split('==')
        if pkg[0] == pkgName:
            current_version = pkg[1]

    # Check pypi for the latest version number
    contents = urllib.request.urlopen('https://pypi.org/pypi/'+pkgName+'/json').read()
    data = json.loads(contents)
    latest_version = data['info']['version']

    return latest_version == current_version
```

Comment: `pip._internal` is not public API. It's even explicitly discouraged in [pip's docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program): "***you must not use pip’s internal APIs in this way***".

Comment: @wim Good to know. I was not aware of this. Thanks for letting me know. I would definitely recommend people using Yusuf Baktir's method instead anyway as it is simpler.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: Remove pip search**

Thanks for the several suggestions. Here is a new version that doesn't use `pip search` but instead pulls the latest version directly from `pypi` as proposed by [Daniel Hill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8200392/daniel-hill). This also resolves the issue with the substring false matches.

```py
def check(name):
    import subprocess
    import sys
    import json
    import urllib.request

    # create dictionary of package versions
    pkgs = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'freeze'])
    keys = [p.decode().split('==')[0] for p in pkgs.split()]
    values = [p.decode().split('==')[1] for p in pkgs.split()]
    d = dict(zip(keys, values)) # dictionary of all package versions

    # retrieve info on latest version
    contents = urllib.request.urlopen('https://pypi.org/pypi/'+name+'/json').read()
    data = json.loads(contents)
    latest_version = data['info']['version']

    if d[name]==latest_version:
        print('Latest version (' + d[name] + ') of '+str(name)+' is installed')
        return True
    else:
        print('Version ' + d[name] + ' of '+str(name)+' not the latest '+latest_version)
        return False

print(check('gekko'))
```

**Original Response**

Here is a fast solution that retrieves latest version information on only the `gekko` package of interest.

```py
def check(name):
    import subprocess
    import sys
    # create dictionary of package versions
    pkgs = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'freeze'])
    keys = [p.decode().split('==')[0] for p in pkgs.split()]
    values = [p.decode().split('==')[1] for p in pkgs.split()]
    d = dict(zip(keys, values)) # dictionary of all package versions

    # retrieve info on latest version
    s = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'search', name])

    if d[name] in s.decode():  # weakness
        print('Latest version (' + d[name] + ') of '+str(name)+' is installed')
        return True
    else:
        print(s.decode())
        return False

print(check('gekko'))
```

This produces the message `Latest version (0.2.3) of gekko is installed` and returns `True` to indicate latest version (or `False` if not the latest version). This may not be the best solution because it only checks for a version substring with `if d[name] in s.decode():` but it is faster than `pip list --outdated` that checks all the packages. This isn't the most reliable method because it will return an incorrect `True` if current installed version is `0.2.3` but latest version is `0.2.30` or `0.2.3a`. An improvement would be to programmatically get the latest version and do a direct comparison.

Comment: Careful with `pip search`.  It uses a deprecated XML-RPC API, and sometimes the search [results are inaccurate/wrong](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/395)  In fact I think it might be removed soon, see [Remove the pip search command #5216](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5216).

Comment: I modified the code to use Daniel's method of pulling the current package version. Another way to get the current gekko version is to do `import gekko` and then `current_version=gekko.__version__` instead of creating a dictionary of all package versions. However, not all packages have a version number accessible in the package.

Answer (score 2):

It's not hard to write a simple script yourself by [querying the PyPI API](https://warehouse.pypa.io/api-reference/json/). With the latest Python 3.8, it's possible using only the standard library (when using Python 3.7 or older, you'll have to install the [`importlib_metadata`](https://pypi.org/project/importlib-metadata/) backport):

```
# check_version.py

import json
import urllib.request
import sys

try:
    from importlib.metadata import version
except ImportError:
    from importlib_metadata import version

from distutils.version import LooseVersion


if __name__ == '__main__':
    name = sys.argv[1]
    installed_version = LooseVersion(version(name))

    # fetch package metadata from PyPI
    pypi_url = f'https://pypi.org/pypi/{name}/json'
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(pypi_url).read().decode()
    latest_version = max(LooseVersion(s) for s in json.loads(response)['releases'].keys())

    print('package:', name, 'installed:', installed_version, 'latest:', latest_version)
```

Usage example:

```
$ python check_version.py setuptools
package: setuptools installed: 41.2.0 latest: 41.6.0
```

If you're happen to have [`packaging`](https://packaging.pypa.io/en/latest/) installed, it's a better alternative to `distutils.version` for version parsing:

```
from distutils.version import LooseVersion

...

LooseVersion(s)
```

becomes

```
from packaging.version import parse

...

parse(s)
```

Comment: This can give different results to pip if additional or alternate indexes are configured for the user (via pip.conf file or PIP_INDEX_URL or PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL env vars)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the accepted answer you can do:

```
pip list --outdated | grep name_of_package
```

Comment: It works well, but it is a bit long.

Answer (score -2):

For `pydicom` these work fine,

```
import pydicom
print(pydicom.__version__) # output is a string: 'x.y.z'
```

or

```
import pydicom
print(pydicom.__version_info__) # output is a tuple: ('x', 'y', 'z')
```